# using tinymce in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tinymce

I want to use TinyMCE in chrome extension.

In simple example, insert TinyMCE into textarea, when i click browseraction.

It's not working.

Please help me!

This is my code. (I use jquery. when click browseraction, insert textarea and apply TinyMCE) 
just insert textarea.. not apply TinyMCE..

***My folder***

- **background.html**
- **content.js**
- **manifest.json**
- **icon.png**
- **tinymce(folder)**
- **jquery-1.7.1.min.js**

> ***[background.html]***

```
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" }, function() {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

> ***[content.js]***

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple"        
    }); 

$("body").append("<textarea>hello</textarea>");
```

> ***[manifest.json]***

```
{
    "name": "NNNyang",
    "description": "TinyMCE test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"],
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "insert TinyMCE"
    }
}
```

Comment: I can tell you that you should select $(body) and not $("body")

Comment: that's not problem. ""$("body").append("<textarea>hello</textarea>");"" is operate well.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I need to do the same thing and I'm running to the exact same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it in the wrong order. You need to have the textarea on your page when you try to call the tinymce initialization. Try this

```
**EDIT:**

$("body").append("<textarea>hello</textarea>");

tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple"        
});
```

Comment: sry, put it the wrong way too, try again using my updated code

Comment: still not working.. I think that this 'background.html'code cannot load all TinyMCE's js files, load only 'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'.. How can load all TinyMCE's js files in chrome extension? I'm crazing now.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like quite an old question, trying to inject TinyMCE into an existing page.

In order to do this in current chrome, you'll need to:

a) use the content_scripts manifest directive, to inject every script you want access to in the page. (in this case, jquery, tinymce, and your own script)

b) in your content.js, setup a chrome RPC receiver, to receive a message action from your background script, using chrome.extension.onRequest.AddListener(...)

c) in your background script, use chrome.browserAction.onClicked.AddListener(..) to setup a trigger function for your browser button which sends an RPC message to your content.js script using chrome.tabs.sendRequest(...)

I have an extension which does this kind of thing with a context menu. You should be able to extrapolate this to a browser-action button..

https://github.com/jeske/BBCodePaste